# How to add new datatype in ODI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I am scripting a ODI task using groovy script.
My requirement is to add new data type under the SQL server and Oracle technology. 
I can add them from the groovy editor but how can I do it using groovy script.
I am using Oracle Data integrator (ODI) and using groovy script for setting up tasks that migrate the data between SQL server to Oracle. Now I want to add new datatype datetmeoffset missing under ODI SQL server technology.
Also want to change some datatype mapping between SQL server and oracle under ODI technology using groovy.
Thanks and Regards,
Santosh Kadam.

Comment: What do you mean by ODI task? Please explain.

Comment: I am using Oracle Data integrator (ODI) and using groovy script for setting up tasks that migrate the data between SQL server to Oracle. Now I want to add new datatype datetmeoffset missing under ODI SQL server technology.

Comment: Do anyone having any idea on how to add new datatype in Oracle Data Integrator (ODI) using groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we able to create new data types using the ODI libraries in java.
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiDataType;
import oracle.odi.domain.topology.OdiTechnology;